# ARToolkit Unity - Camera blank (only black) when Playing

Tags: unity-game-engine, artoolkit

[image]
I want to create Augmented Reality using Unity and ARToolkit but when done then play the camera was blank. I follow this tutorial from [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8O-XKQ2Avo)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use one of the example scenes that come with the ARToolKit Unity package as a starting point.

Those scenes should work fine and you can check the differences with yours.

Comment: i've using the example scene and its doesnt work also

Comment: Then the problem must be in the camera and the access to it.

Comment: Hi @shalafi . I have problem with unity3d blank scene when open project? Can you help me? Here is the link to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39952401/5241603