# Unity3D scene blank in ubuntu

Tags: unity-game-engine, ubuntu-14.04, deb

I am very new with unity3d. I download unity3d in format .deb file and install it. Is it because it missed configuration or something not support? Thank

[image: .]

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem with Unity running on a Debian machine.

After spending half a day fighting it, the most simple solution worked:

I simply changed the layout, causing the scene to re-render, and changed it back.

Click on `Window` > `Layout` > `2 by 3`

Than choose your favorite layout.

Comment: So simple! That was my problem

Comment: Works for me too!

Answer (score 2):

have you checked all your graphics drivers? this black screen can happen if it is not all updated, go to the terminal in Ubuntu and try this command - sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel, Once you've done that click this link and try installing the new build of Unity if you haven't

http://beta.unity3d.com/download/f4fc8fd4067d/public_download.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is strange, I used unity3D on Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 and it worked fine, if I remember correctly not all versions are good (I mean unity versions and linux versions).

I've seen a similar problem on other apps that was solved by resizing the window (somehow that forced a redraw of the content that moving did not)

Comment: Thank for your answer. I try to resize window, but not workk